# Generate a tree from a list of URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, python-3.7

I have a list of multiple URLs, and some directories have multiple files with different extensions and so on. Example:

```
    List = [
         "http://www.example.com/folder1",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image1.png",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image2.png",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file2.txt",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file3.txt",
         ...
    ]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to filter those URLs in order to get a list that will only have the URL of the folder and one URL of each different extension. Something like this:

```
    List = [
         "http://www.example.com/folder1",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image1.png",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3",
         "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt",
         ...
    ]
```

At the moment I'm stuck on how can I generate some kind of tree out of this, so that then I can traverse it and remove the duplicated files.

I've tried some different approaches, but I'm still kinda new to Python.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URLs follow that simple format, you can filter the list using a `dict` to keep track of which directories were used:

```
List = [
     "http://www.example.com/folder1",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image1.png",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image2.png",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file2.txt",
     "http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file3.txt",
     ...
]

dirnames = {}
filtered = []

for url in List:
    dirname = os.path.dirname(url)
    dirnames.setdefault(dirname, {})
    extension = os.path.splitext(url)[1]

    if extension not in dirnames[dirname]:
        dirnames[dirname][extension] = True
        filtered.append(url)

print(filtered)
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for. Mainly the "os.path.dirname" hint, didn't know I could do that. Managed to adapt to my context and its working. And its pretty simple to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
import itertools, re
data = ['http://www.example.com/folder1', 'http://www.example.com/folder1', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image1.png', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image2.png', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file2.txt', 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file3.txt']
def group(d, path = []):
   new_d = [[a, [j for _, *j in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
   for a, c in new_d:
      _d, _fold, _path = [i[0] for i in c if len(i) == 1], [], []
      for i in _d:
        if not re.findall('\.\w+$', i):
          if i not in _fold:
             yield '/'.join(path+[a]+[i])
             _fold.append(i)
        else:
           if i.split('.')[-1] not in _path:
              yield '/'.join(path+[a]+[i])
              _path.append(i.split('.')[-1])
      r = [i for i in c if len(i) != 1]
      yield from group(r, path+[a])

_data = [[a, *b.split('/')] for a, b in map(lambda x:re.split('(?<=\.com)/', x), data)]
print(list(group(_data)))
```

Output:

```
['http://www.example.com/folder1', 
 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2', 
 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3', 
 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/image1.png', 
 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.txt', 
 'http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/file1.txt']
```

Comment: This works, but it is a bit too complex for what I needed. Specially for others to understand whats going on, but I'm saving this method also :) thanks!